# Jasmine JS Tests only fail when run headless

Tags: jasmine, automated-tests, travis-ci

So several tests that test for very basic behavior:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(window.location.hash == '#admin'){
    $(document).on('change', '#undelete-type-select', undeleteManager.typeSelected);
    $(document).on('change', '#undelete-manual-type-select', undeleteManager.idsSelected);
    $(document).on('click', '.undelete-link', undeleteManager.recoverByLink);
    $(document).on('click', 'i.icon-repeat', undeleteManager.startOver);
    $(document).on('click', '#undelete-ids-submit', undeleteManager.undeleteById);
  }
});
```

When I run the tests in the browser they pass. When I run the tests on travis they all fail. Here's an example of a failing test:

```
describe('when #undelete-type-select changes', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    $('#undelete-type-select').val('ticket');
    $('#undelete-type-select').change();
  });

  it('should go to step 2', function() {
    expect($('#status').html()).toMatch(/Step 2/);
  });
});
```

The error basically indicates that it's still on step 1:

Expected 'Step 1: What type of content would you like to recover?' to match /Step 2/.
          Error: Expected 'Step 1: What type of content would you like to recover?' to match /Step 2/.

Thoughts? Help?

Comment: I thought about this more and I'm thinking it's one of two things:

1. the bindings aren't binding for some reason or...
2. the .click() method doesn't work in headless mode.

Comment: Coworker found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31348032/jasmine-tests-pass-in-chrome-and-firefox-but-fail-with-phantomjs

grr...